# Более быстрые способы установить лейауты и виджеты в них в PyQt5

Tags: python, pyqt5, pyside6

Сколько видел, обычно создание виджета, установка в него лейаута, создание второго виджета и установка уже его в созданный ранее лейаут хоть и делается в несколько строк

```
widget = QWidget()
layout = QVBoxLayout()
widget.setLayout(layout)
label = QLabel("Текст")
layout.addWidget(label)
```

Но даже это очень долго, особенно если подобного много. Наверняка же должен быть способ передавать всю информацию о лейаутах как аргументы, например:

```
widget = QWidget(layout=QVBoxLayout())
label = QLabel("Текст", parentLayout=widget.layout())
```

Две строчки, пару параметров, готово. Есть что-то такое?

Comment: Нет, такого нет. Рекомендую освоить QtDesigner, чтобы компоновать виджеты в ручную легко и быстро

Comment: @AlexanderChernin работал в нём, он мягко говоря кривой и неудобный.

Comment: Хм, странно. 15 лет в нём работаю и всё удобно